# How to install a Titanium module

Tags: ios, module, titanium

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/imagefactory) module in a Titanium app.

I've downloaded this [zip](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/imagefactory/mobile/ios/ti.imagefactory-iphone-1.1.1.zip) and I've tried to copy it in my Project Folder, at same level as Resources, tiapp.xml, README, etc. Is it correct?

If I build the project now, zip file disappear but it doesn't create a modules folder and when I've tried to configure the app to use it, I try to modify tiapp.xml but the module doesn't appear.

If I update tiapp manually with this format:

```
 <module version="$MODULE_VERSION">$MODULE_ID</module>
```

it doesn't recognise it.

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried also to add the zip to ~/Library/Application Support/Titanium but nothing changes.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following steps.

1. Unzip the zip file
2. Copy the folder to your Appcelerator titanium's iPhone module folder.
      If you didn't changed the install path the normal path will be:
      `~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone`
3. Go to the TiApp Editor page of your project.
   a. If you are using the GUI interface add the module on the right side window.
   b. If you are using the xml file, add the below lines to your tiapp.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've tried to unzip the zip and I can't. Maybe it's damaged. Do you know how I can get the module?

Comment: @A.Vila: Is that unzipped package contains any folder like com.modulname.foo ?

Comment: @A.Vila: add the ti.imagefactory folder to the specified path

Comment: Sorry, I think I haven't explained well. I can't unzip the file on Mac it appears a .zip.cpgz file and on Windows it says that file has a unrecognisable format or it's damaged.

Comment: @A.Vila: I think you need to re-download it. I downloaded the file on Windows and successfully extracted. It seems your downloaded file was corrupted.